# Seeking SQL syntax with errors using HAVING with assigned variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for the SQL syntax to use HAVING in the following statement:

```
DECLARE @ORIG_LAT AS FLOAT = 40.4882011413574; 
DECLARE @ORIG_LONG AS FLOAT = -80.1939010620117;
DECLARE @DISTANCE AS INT; 

SELECT LATITUDE_DEG, LONGITUDE_DEG,SQRT( 
    POWER(69.1 * (LATITUDE_DEG - @ORIG_LAT), 2) + 
    POWER(69.1 * (@ORIG_LONG - LONGITUDE_DEG) * COS(LATITUDE_DEG / 57.3), 2)) AS DISTANCE 
FROM NAVAIDS 
HAVING DISTANCE < 80 --error 
ORDER BY DISTANCE ASC;
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Invalid column name 'distance'.

It's ok with the `ORDER BY` but I don't understand why it doesn't like the HAVING. Any help with direction? It is SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it (no extra `<br>` needed)! If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, you can't use an aliased column directly. The easiest solution would be to wrap your statement in a subselect and apply your clause on that.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  LATITUDE_DEG
                  , LONGITUDE_DEG
                  , SQRT(
                      POWER(69.1 * (LATITUDE_DEG - @ORIG_LAT), 2) +
                      POWER(69.1 * (@ORIG_LONG - LONGITUDE_DEG) * COS(LATITUDE_DEG / 57.3), 2)) AS DISTANCE
          FROM    NAVAIDS
        ) q          
WHERE DISTANCE < 80
ORDER BY 
        DISTANCE ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did have to add a GROUP BY to it to compile so the end result was:

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from (
    SELECT LATITUDE_DEG, LONGITUDE_DEG, SQRT( 
        POWER(69.1 * (LATITUDE_DEG - @ORIG_LAT), 2) 
        POWER(69.1 * (@ORIG_LONG - LONGITUDE_DEG) * COS(LATITUDE_DEG / 57.3), 2)
    ) AS DISTANCE 
    FROM NAVAIDS 
) a 
WHERE DISTANCE < 80 
ORDER BY DISTANCE
```